# ubuntu16.04 takes about 100sec to boot

Tags: boot

i am new to ubuntu.
i did something wrong while using GParted [this is how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnVmj.png).
i tried some solutions but they didn't help me.

shashank@shashank-H61MGV3:~$ systemd-analyze blame
         10.654s dev-sda4.device
          6.773s keyboard-setup.service
          6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
          4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
          4.285s apparmor.service
          3.986s snapd.service
          3.977s ModemManager.service
          2.979s NetworkManager.service
          2.640s accounts-daemon.service
          2.097s grub-common.service
          1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
          1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
          1.399s thermald.service
          1.103s console-setup.service
          1.022s lightdm.service
          1.020s rsyslog.service
           861ms udisks2.service
           702ms ondemand.service
           678ms polkitd.service
           672ms systemd-modules-load.service
           666ms systemd-journald.service
 ESCOC

ine.service
dev.service

ce

vice
e

rvice
e
 ESCOD

```
     10.654s dev-sda4.device
      6.773s keyboard-setup.service
      6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
      4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      4.285s apparmor.service
      3.986s snapd.service
      3.977s ModemManager.service
      2.979s NetworkManager.service
      2.640s accounts-daemon.service
      2.097s grub-common.service
      1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.399s thermald.service
      1.103s console-setup.service
      1.022s lightdm.service
      1.020s rsyslog.service
       861ms udisks2.service
       702ms ondemand.service
       678ms polkitd.service
       672ms systemd-modules-load.service
       666ms systemd-journald.service
```

ESCOD

```
     10.654s dev-sda4.device
      6.773s keyboard-setup.service
      6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
      4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      4.285s apparmor.service
      3.986s snapd.service
      3.977s ModemManager.service
      2.979s NetworkManager.service
      2.640s accounts-daemon.service
      2.097s grub-common.service
      1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.399s thermald.service
      1.103s console-setup.service
      1.022s lightdm.service
      1.020s rsyslog.service
       861ms udisks2.service
       702ms ondemand.service
       678ms polkitd.service
       672ms systemd-modules-load.service
       666ms systemd-journald.service
```

ESCOC

ine.service
dev.service

ce

vice
e

rvice
e
 ESCOC

ESCOC

ESCOC

ESCOD

ESCOD

ESCOD

ine.service
dev.service

ce

vice
e

rvice
e
 ESCOD

```
     10.654s dev-sda4.device
      6.773s keyboard-setup.service
      6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
      4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      4.285s apparmor.service
      3.986s snapd.service
      3.977s ModemManager.service
      2.979s NetworkManager.service
      2.640s accounts-daemon.service
      2.097s grub-common.service
      1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.399s thermald.service
      1.103s console-setup.service
      1.022s lightdm.service
      1.020s rsyslog.service
       861ms udisks2.service
       702ms ondemand.service
       678ms polkitd.service
       672ms systemd-modules-load.service
       666ms systemd-journald.service
```

ESCOD

```
     10.654s dev-sda4.device
      6.773s keyboard-setup.service
      6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
      4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      4.285s apparmor.service
      3.986s snapd.service
      3.977s ModemManager.service
      2.979s NetworkManager.service
      2.640s accounts-daemon.service
      2.097s grub-common.service
      1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.399s thermald.service
      1.103s console-setup.service
      1.022s lightdm.service
      1.020s rsyslog.service
       861ms udisks2.service
       702ms ondemand.service
       678ms polkitd.service
       672ms systemd-modules-load.service
       666ms systemd-journald.service
```

ESCOD

```
     10.654s dev-sda4.device
     10.654s dev-sda4.device
      6.773s keyboard-setup.service
      6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
      4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      4.285s apparmor.service
      3.986s snapd.service
      3.977s ModemManager.service
      2.979s NetworkManager.service
      2.640s accounts-daemon.service
      2.097s grub-common.service
      1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.399s thermald.service
      1.103s console-setup.service
      1.022s lightdm.service
      1.020s rsyslog.service
       861ms udisks2.service
       702ms ondemand.service
       678ms polkitd.service
       672ms systemd-modules-load.service
       666ms systemd-journald.service
       600ms irqbalance.service
       587ms gpu-manager.service
       521ms apport.service
       453ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       451ms dev-hugepages.mount
       434ms systemd-logind.service
       433ms avahi-daemon.service
       433ms dev-mqueue.mount
       422ms dns-clean.service
       379ms networking.service
       348ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       343ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       314ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       310ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       270ms ufw.service
       269ms speech-dispatcher.service
       260ms pppd-dns.service
       260ms pppd-dns.service
     10.654s dev-sda4.device
      6.773s keyboard-setup.service
      6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
      4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      4.285s apparmor.service
      3.986s snapd.service
      3.977s ModemManager.service
      2.979s NetworkManager.service
      2.640s accounts-daemon.service
      2.097s grub-common.service
      1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.399s thermald.service
      1.103s console-setup.service
      1.022s lightdm.service
      1.020s rsyslog.service
       861ms udisks2.service
       702ms ondemand.service
       678ms polkitd.service
       672ms systemd-modules-load.service
       666ms systemd-journald.service
```

ESCOD

```
     10.654s dev-sda4.device
      6.773s keyboard-setup.service
      6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
      4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      4.285s apparmor.service
      3.986s snapd.service
      3.977s ModemManager.service
      2.979s NetworkManager.service
      2.640s accounts-daemon.service
      2.097s grub-common.service
      1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.399s thermald.service
      1.103s console-setup.service
      1.022s lightdm.service
      1.020s rsyslog.service
       861ms udisks2.service
       702ms ondemand.service
       678ms polkitd.service
       672ms systemd-modules-load.service
       666ms systemd-journald.service
```

ESCOD

```
     10.654s dev-sda4.device
      6.773s keyboard-setup.service
      6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
      4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      4.285s apparmor.service
      3.986s snapd.service
      3.977s ModemManager.service
      2.979s NetworkManager.service
      2.640s accounts-daemon.service
      2.097s grub-common.service
      1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.399s thermald.service
      1.103s console-setup.service
      1.022s lightdm.service
      1.020s rsyslog.service
       861ms udisks2.service
       702ms ondemand.service
       678ms polkitd.service
       672ms systemd-modules-load.service
       666ms systemd-journald.service
```

ESCOD

```
     10.654s dev-sda4.device
      6.773s keyboard-setup.service
      6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
      4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      4.285s apparmor.service
      3.986s snapd.service
      3.977s ModemManager.service
      2.979s NetworkManager.service
      2.640s accounts-daemon.service
      2.097s grub-common.service
      1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.399s thermald.service
      1.103s console-setup.service
      1.022s lightdm.service
      1.020s rsyslog.service
       861ms udisks2.service
       702ms ondemand.service
       678ms polkitd.service
       672ms systemd-modules-load.service
       666ms systemd-journald.service
```

...skipping...
         10.654s dev-sda4.device
          6.773s keyboard-setup.service
          6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
          4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
          4.285s apparmor.service
          3.986s snapd.service
          3.977s ModemManager.service
          2.979s NetworkManager.service
          2.640s accounts-daemon.service
          2.097s grub-common.service
          1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
          1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
          1.399s thermald.service
          1.103s console-setup.service
          1.022s lightdm.service
          1.020s rsyslog.service
           861ms udisks2.service
           702ms ondemand.service
           678ms polkitd.service
           672ms systemd-modules-load.service
           666ms systemd-journald.service
           600ms irqbalance.service
           587ms gpu-manager.service
           521ms apport.service
           453ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           451ms dev-hugepages.mount
           434ms systemd-logind.service
           433ms avahi-daemon.service
           433ms dev-mqueue.mount
           422ms dns-clean.service
           379ms networking.service
           348ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           343ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           314ms systemd-user-sessions.service

```
     10.654s dev-sda4.device
      6.773s keyboard-setup.service
      6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
      4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      4.285s apparmor.service
      3.986s snapd.service
      3.977s ModemManager.service
      2.979s NetworkManager.service
      2.640s accounts-daemon.service
      2.097s grub-common.service
      1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.399s thermald.service
      1.103s console-setup.service
      1.022s lightdm.service
      1.020s rsyslog.service
       861ms udisks2.service
       702ms ondemand.service
       678ms polkitd.service
       672ms systemd-modules-load.service
       666ms systemd-journald.service
       600ms irqbalance.service
       587ms gpu-manager.service
       521ms apport.service
       453ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       451ms dev-hugepages.mount
       434ms systemd-logind.service
       433ms avahi-daemon.service
       433ms dev-mqueue.mount
       422ms dns-clean.service
       379ms networking.service
       348ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       343ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       314ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       310ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       270ms ufw.service
       269ms speech-dispatcher.service
       260ms pppd-dns.service
       434ms systemd-logind.service
       433ms avahi-daemon.service
       433ms dev-mqueue.mount
       422ms dns-clean.service
       379ms networking.service
       348ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       343ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       314ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       310ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       270ms ufw.service
       269ms speech-dispatcher.service
       260ms pppd-dns.service
       434ms systemd-logind.service
       433ms avahi-daemon.service
       433ms dev-mqueue.mount
       422ms dns-clean.service
       379ms networking.service
       348ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       343ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       314ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       310ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       270ms ufw.service
       269ms speech-dispatcher.service
       260ms pppd-dns.service
       434ms systemd-logind.service
       433ms avahi-daemon.service
       433ms dev-mqueue.mount
       422ms dns-clean.service
       379ms networking.service
       348ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       343ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       314ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       310ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       270ms ufw.service
       269ms speech-dispatcher.service
       260ms pppd-dns.service
       243ms systemd-udevd.service
       213ms wpa_supplicant.service
       208ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       199ms alsa-restore.service
       160ms resolvconf.service
       148ms colord.service
       142ms systemd-timesyncd.service
        96ms upower.service
        94ms systemd-hostnamed.service
        89ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        64ms systemd-random-seed.service
        54ms plymouth-start.service
        49ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
        45ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        45ms setvtrgb.service
        23ms user@1000.service
         9ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         4ms ureadahead-stop.service
         3ms rtkit-daemon.service
         3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         2ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
         1ms rc-local.service
       677us snapd.socket

     10.654s dev-sda4.device
      6.773s keyboard-setup.service
      6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
      4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      4.285s apparmor.service
      3.986s snapd.service
      3.977s ModemManager.service
      2.979s NetworkManager.service
      2.640s accounts-daemon.service
      2.097s grub-common.service
      1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      1.399s thermald.service
      1.103s console-setup.service
      1.022s lightdm.service
      1.020s rsyslog.service
       861ms udisks2.service
       702ms ondemand.service
       678ms polkitd.service
       672ms systemd-modules-load.service
       666ms systemd-journald.service
       600ms irqbalance.service
       587ms gpu-manager.service
       521ms apport.service
       453ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       451ms dev-hugepages.mount
       434ms systemd-logind.service
       433ms avahi-daemon.service
       433ms dev-mqueue.mount
       422ms dns-clean.service
       379ms networking.service
       348ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       343ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       314ms systemd-user-sessions.service
```

mark: 
          6.773s keyboard-setup.service
          6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
          4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
          4.285s apparmor.service
          3.986s snapd.service
          3.977s ModemManager.service
          2.979s NetworkManager.service
          2.640s accounts-daemon.service
          2.097s grub-common.service
          1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
          1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
          1.399s thermald.service
          1.103s console-setup.service
          1.022s lightdm.service
          1.020s rsyslog.service
           861ms udisks2.service
           702ms ondemand.service
           678ms polkitd.service
           672ms systemd-modules-load.service
           666ms systemd-journald.service
           600ms irqbalance.service
           587ms gpu-manager.service
          6.773s keyboard-setup.service
          6.771s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          6.547s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          6.056s systemd-sysctl.service
          4.959s apt-daily-upgrade.service
          4.285s apparmor.service
          3.986s snapd.service
          3.977s ModemManager.service
          2.979s NetworkManager.service
          2.640s accounts-daemon.service
          2.097s grub-common.service
          1.879s plymouth-read-write.service
          1.449s iio-sensor-proxy.service
          1.399s thermald.service
          1.103s console-setup.service
          1.022s lightdm.service
          1.020s rsyslog.service
           861ms udisks2.service
           702ms ondemand.service
           678ms polkitd.service
           672ms systemd-modules-load.service
           666ms systemd-journald.service
           600ms irqbalance.service
           587ms gpu-manager.service
           521ms apport.service
           453ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           451ms dev-hugepages.mount
           434ms systemd-logind.service
           433ms avahi-daemon.service
           433ms dev-mqueue.mount
           422ms dns-clean.service
           379ms networking.service
           348ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           343ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           314ms systemd-user-sessions.service
           310ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
           270ms ufw.service
           269ms speech-dispatcher.service
           260ms pppd-dns.service
           434ms systemd-logind.service
           433ms avahi-daemon.service
           433ms dev-mqueue.mount
           422ms dns-clean.service
           379ms networking.service
           348ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           343ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           314ms systemd-user-sessions.service
           310ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
           270ms ufw.service
           269ms speech-dispatcher.service
           260ms pppd-dns.service
           243ms systemd-udevd.service
           213ms wpa_supplicant.service
           208ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           199ms alsa-restore.service
           160ms resolvconf.service
           148ms colord.service
           142ms systemd-timesyncd.service
            96ms upower.service
            94ms systemd-hostnamed.service
            89ms systemd-journal-flush.service
            64ms systemd-random-seed.service
...skipping...
           434ms systemd-logind.service
           433ms avahi-daemon.service
           433ms dev-mqueue.mount
           422ms dns-clean.service
           379ms networking.service
           348ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           343ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           314ms systemd-user-sessions.service
           310ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
           270ms ufw.service
           269ms speech-dispatcher.service
           260ms pppd-dns.service
           243ms systemd-udevd.service
           213ms wpa_supplicant.service
           208ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           199ms alsa-restore.service
           160ms resolvconf.service
           148ms colord.service
           142ms systemd-timesyncd.service
            96ms upower.service
            94ms systemd-hostnamed.service
            89ms systemd-journal-flush.service
            64ms systemd-random-seed.service
            54ms plymouth-start.service
lines 30-52/63 82%

Comment: can you explain what is exactly your question? And what do you do wrong on gparted (crypt some partition?)

Comment: Post `systemd-analyze blame` results.

Comment: i think the swap partition was moved on a disk, so the UUID for it was no longer valid.